# String2 to be deduced from String1

Tags: string

need help with a shell scripting

String1="/var/log/messages; is a critical file which stores logs. /var/log/secure; stores user's login attempts. /var/log/tallylog; stores login tally information."

Need this:
String2="/var/log/messages /var/log/secure /var/log/tallylog"

Basically the word starts with / and contains two slashes and ends with a semicolon.
Such words should be pasted one after the other separated by space and saved as String2

still trying to understand the logic to make that happen.

Comment: And which language or script engine are you going to do this in?

Comment: awk sed bash scripting

Comment: You already have that string (it's in your question), so what is the question ?

Comment: @Luuk I think they are looking for a way to do a pattern matching operation that will locate all substrings that _"starts with / and contains two slashes and ends with a semicolon"_ and then join them together with spaces to form a new string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were looking for a function or not, but here is python code that uses regex to accomplish your task for the stings you provided. This can later be used in a function if you want to apply it to other strings.

```
import re

string1 = "/var/log/messages; is a critical file which stores logs. /var/log/secure; stores user's login attempts. /var/log/tallylog; stores login tally information."

# Use regular expression to find words starting with '/' and ending with ';'
matches = re.findall(r'\/(\S+?);', string1)

# Join the matches into a single string separated by space
string2 = ' '.join(matches)

print("String2:", string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard BASH commands:

```bash
String1="/var/log/messages; is a critical file which stores logs. /var/log/secure; stores user's login attempts. /var/log/tallylog; stores login tally information."

String2=`echo $String1 | awk -F"[;.] " '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}'`

printf "\n--------------\n$String2\n--------------\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [Powershell on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.4)

```
#!/bin/bash

String1="/var/log/messages; is a critical file which stores logs. /var/log/secure; stores user's login attempts. /var/log/tallylog; stores login tally information."
pwsh -CommandWithArgs '$args | Select-String -Pattern "/" | % { $_ -Replace ";","" } | Join-String -Separator " "' $String1
```

output:

```
/var/log/messages /var/log/secure /var/log/tallylog
```